# Spark Cassandra Join ClassCastException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to join two Cassandra tables with:
`t1.join(t2, Seq("some column"), "left")`
I am getting the below error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple8 cannot be cast to scala.Tuple7 at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.execution.CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.apply(CassandraDirectJoinStrategy.scala:27)
```

I am using cassandra v3.11.13 and Spark 3.3.0. The code dependencies:

```
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.11" % Test,
      "com.github.mrpowers" %% "spark-fast-tests" % "1.0.0" % Test,
      "graphframes" % "graphframes" % "0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12" % Provided,
      "org.rogach" %% "scallop" % "4.1.0" % Provided,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.1.2" % Provided,
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % "3.1.2" % Provided,
      "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "3.2.0" % Provided)
```

Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) does not support Apache Spark 3.3.0 yet and I suspect that is the reason it's not working though I haven't done any verification myself.

Support for Spark 3.3.0 has been requested in [SPARKC-686](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-686) but the amount of work required is significant so stay tuned.

The [latest supported Spark version is 3.2](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#version-compatibility) using spark-cassandra-connector 3.2. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Erick, I will try Spark 3.2 and let you know

Comment: Great to hear you got it working with Spark 3.2. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[this commit](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/commit/9eb9e81999c2a89ed7cb7ca04741b730eb54be75)
adds initial support for Spark 3.3.x, although it is awaiting RC's/publish at the time of this comment, so you would need to build and package the jars yourself for the time being to begin making use of them to resolve the above error when using spark 3.3. This could be a good opportunity to provide any feedback on any subsequent RC's, as an active user.

I will update this comment when RC's/stable releases are available, which should resolve the above issue for others hitting this issue. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to add this a comment to thread above.